# Show a DialogFragment within a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have been trying to show a DialogFragment within a Fragment without success. Here my code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null && !user.isEmailVerified()) {
        InfoDialogFragment dialog = new InfoDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "InfoDialogFragment");
    }
}
```

Whenever That fragment is on the screen, the screen gets darker and when I touch the screen it regains its normal contrast, but I can't see the dialog fragment. 
What am I missing?

Here is the code for the DialogFragment:

```
public class InfoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
private InfoDialogListener listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the InfoDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        listener = (InfoDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement DeleteListListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, null);

    TextView message = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.message);
    message.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.user_not_verified));
    //
    Button ok = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onDialogOKClick(InfoDialogFragment.this);
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}


public interface InfoDialogListener {
    void onDialogOKClick(DialogFragment dialog);

}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: You should just have a function that shows a dialog fragment in the fragment's calling activity - use the FragmentInteractionListener pattern that google puts into its boilerplate fragment/activity code. Sounds like it is trying to show the dialog though

Comment: put InfoDialogFragment code here

Comment: Can we see InfoDialogFragment code?

Comment: did you try whit getChildFragmentManager()

Answer (score 7):

Use `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`. These are different instances.

Comment: this is critical.  thank you. from fragment we should use childFragmentManager

Answer (score 0):

In fact I was missing a line of code in the InfoDialogFragment class.

```
builder.setView(layout);
```

It took me 2 days to figure it out.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor in your InfoDialogFragment class and you can show it like this:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment(NextDate);
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
```